# Can Google Page Speed be exploited or tricked to show unrealistic results?

Tags: javascript, php, google-pagespeed

I have hired a freelance developer to optimize my Wordpress website. After he has made the changes, Google Page Speed started giving me a score of 99 / 100. That has made me suspicious, as 99 on Google Page Speed seemed unrealistic.

The following has further raised my suspicions:

```
Maximum DOM Depth
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=" type="image/x-icon">

3
```

```
JavaScript execution time 0
```

```
Minimizes main-thread work

0.1 s
```

Comment: Why would you say **99 on Google Page Speed seemed unrealistic**? and also what would you get after removing Maximum DOM Depth value?

Comment: No, it can't be hacked. But he could be pointing it at a blank sub-page, with no DOM

Comment: Share the URL, so we can check it for you..

Comment: What's your exact question? Have you checked what your developer changed to make all that work? Probably he just returns an empty page if the request comes from a given IP range or user agent